# Auto Logoff of ms Access

Tags: ms-access, shutdown

I manage an access database that runs on a server and utilizes the split tables and front end option. When i have to make updates i have to get everyone out of the database and this often is difficult. There is always one or two peopl who forget to log off after hours or dont exit when requested. I found a few third party access applications that say they work but i cant find any for access 2010. i guess in access 2010 they changed how user permissions work and this messes up the previous solutions.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this approach so I can't validate that it works, but have you seen \ tried this?

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3548586/Auto-Logout-Users-for-DB-Maintenance.htm

Essentially the idea is you open and hide a form at startup that periodically queries a table in search of the log off flag.

If the flag is not set the form resets its timer and queries again at some regular interval.

If the flag is set the form is displayed with a message to the user that he\she will be logged off in X minutes. When the countdown reaches 0 the form closes the application.

As far as I can tell, the biggest key to this approach is that the flag needs to be set in the back-end database so that all front-end clients see the same data.

Comment: i had looked at that option but could not get it to work with across a network. I did find this that works with a spit database and has worked  during my initial testing [link](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/TimeOut-Forceoff-re-edit-t672964.html)

Comment: The Time Out Force Off is a much better solution listed below.