# How to automatically logout users or have user sessions timeout in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

One of our clients has an MS Access database that keeps crashing. Our IT department thinks its crashing because, 1. There is only one login, 2. multiple people are using the same login at the same time on different machines, 3. the same people are leaving their session logged in when not using the db.

I think this problem could be solved by switching to SQL Server, and everyone having their own login. One, it would help with audit trails and two, concurrency, session timeouts, and other settings are available. The problem with this solution is the clients do not want to move to SQL Server.

So my question is, does Access have a feature to automatically logout a users session after X amount of time of inactivity? If so, could anyone provide documentation or links on how to enable this feature?

Comment: I believe the answer is NO. I have seen numerous threads discussing how to close Access after period of inactivity. Google or Bing should help. http://blueclaw-db.com/download/user_inactivity_logout.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055103/auto-logoff-of-ms-access

Comment: Well, it not clear what you mean by one logon? That would not effect anything. Using the term logon here is not clear. this database is split right? And the application is installed on each workstation. If it is not then this is the #1 reason for un-stable applications. What  kind of logon you speak of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a hidden form with the following code on the on timer Property (timer interval set to 1000)

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
' IDLEMINUTES determines how much idle time to wait for before
   ' running the IdleTimeDetected subroutine.
   Const IDLEMINUTES = 60

   Static PrevControlName As String
   Static PrevFormName As String
   Static ExpiredTime

   Dim ActiveFormName As String
   Dim ActiveControlName As String
   Dim ExpiredMinutes

   On Error Resume Next

   ' Get the active form and control name.

   ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
   If Err Then
      ActiveFormName = "No Active Form"
      Err = 0
   End If

   ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
      If Err Then
      ActiveControlName = "No Active Control"
      Err = 0
   End If

   ' Record the current active names and reset ExpiredTime if:
   '    1. They have not been recorded yet (code is running
   '       for the first time).
   '    2. The previous names are different than the current ones
   '       (the user has done something different during the timer
   '        interval).
   If (PrevControlName = "") Or (PrevFormName = "") _
     Or (ActiveFormName <> PrevFormName) _
     Or (ActiveControlName <> PrevControlName) Then
      PrevControlName = ActiveControlName
      PrevFormName = ActiveFormName
      ExpiredTime = 0
   Else
      ' ...otherwise the user was idle during the time interval, so
      ' increment the total expired time.
      ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval
   End If

   ' Does the total expired time exceed the IDLEMINUTES?
   ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000) / 60
   If ExpiredMinutes >= IDLEMINUTES Then
      ' ...if so, then reset the expired time to zero...
      ExpiredTime = 0
      ' ...and call the IdleTimeDetected subroutine.
      IdleTimeDetected ExpiredMinutes
   End If
End Sub

Sub IdleTimeDetected(ExpiredMinutes)
   DoCmd.OpenForm "CountToExit"
End Sub
```

Create your self a popup form with the following on  the timer setting as well.

```
' GRACEMINUTES determines how much idle time to count down once this form
' is opened before quitting the Access application.
Const GRACEMINUTES = 1
Static ElapsedTime As Integer
Dim TimeRemaining As Integer
Dim intMinutes As Integer
Dim intSeconds As Integer
Dim strTimePassed As String
Dim strOutput As String

On Error Resume Next
ElapsedTime = ElapsedTime + 1    ' Counts seconds instead of milliseconds.
ElapsedMinutes = ElapsedTime / 60
TimeRemaining = (GRACEMINUTES * 60) - ElapsedTime

 ' Has the countdown timer run out?
If TimeRemaining <= 0 Or Not IsNumeric(TimeRemaining) Then
 ' ...if so, then exit Access.
   strOutput = "0:00"
   Application.Quit acSaveNo
Else
   intMinutes = Fix(TimeRemaining / 60)
   intSeconds = TimeRemaining - (intMinutes * 60)
   strOutput = Format(intMinutes, "0") & ":" & Format(intSeconds, "00")
End If
    Me.Label3.Caption = "Auto shutdown timer: " & strOutput
End Sub
```

Launch that hidden form with your autoexec and it will check one a second to see if the person has changed windows in Access. After 60 minutes of not doing anything they will getting a warning window telling them they have 60 seconds to close the popup window before access saves and exits.

Answer (score 1):

one of the reason why access is crashing is because of the size of the data. if i remember it right, the limitation is around 2GB. it will help you to minimize the crashing if you do the compact & repair every time the user close the application. You may change it by updating the setting of the access db.

[image]